# Time Complexity for Array Max Duplicate

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, big-o

Using only an array for a data structure, what would be the fastest time complexity in finding duplicate max values in the array?

I am thinking one loop is needed to find the max value and another loop would be needed to find if there are any duplicates. Each loop would have to touch each element once so it would be linear time complexity O(n). Given 2 loops we would have O(n) * O(n) = O(n^2).

Does this sound right or does anyone think it can all be done in one loop to keep the time complexity O(n).

I've looked the problem up, but I see fancy solutions like using a hash table. I need to use an array.

Comment: I agree that your solution is fine as-is.  It could be "optimized" to use just one loop but that won't affect the complexity, and it is doubtful that it would make it much faster.  (And the flip-side is that doing it in one loop makes the logic more complicated.)

Comment: Also ... those fancy solutions that use a hash table would almost certainly be slower for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a fine solution, you've just analyzed it incorrectly.

You do one loop to find the maximum value, and then you do another loop to find duplicates of the maximum value.  That isn't a loop inside another loop, that's a loop after another loop -- and that's not O(n) * O(n), it's O(n) + O(n), which is just O(n) again.

No hash tables.  No fancy data structures.  You already have a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's perspective. Okay so a loop inside of a loop, as long as every element is touched would be O(n^2), but 2 O(n)  simplifies to O(n).

Comment: So, O(n) is good but do you think that is as good as we can do? I think it is because every element has to be touched once in a loop. So linear is the best it's gonna get using an an array.

Comment: You have to visit every element, so yes, you can't do better than O(n).

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I had to get the count of max duplicates which would have been easy, but I really need to get the indices of the max duplicates. It seems like the time complexity should be the same, but I am unsure on the logic to accomplish that. Can't have variables to store index values because we would never know how many indices will have a max value.

Comment: Well, in the worst case, you can do three loops: one to find the max value, one to count the duplicates, and one to fill an array that holds all the indices, since you'll know how big to make the array.  (You can actually combine the loops to find the max value and to count the duplicates, but I won't spoil that part.)

Comment: I don't need to count the duplicates. That was my mistake. I just need to get the index where every occurrence of a max value is.

Comment: Sure, but where are you going to store them?  You'll need an array.  You'll need to _create_ that array.  When you create that array, you'll need a length.  That length is the count of duplicates.  So you'll want to count them.  (Or a `List`, which would be simpler, but it's not clear you can use that.)

Comment: I see where your going but not sure what the code will look like. As for the List, do you mean a linked list? As long as what we have to begin with is an array and a List is what we are using to operate on it I think it would be fine.

Comment: Well, I'd do the whole thing with the count variable, and then I'd write `int[] indices = new int[count];`, and then I'd fill that in...

Comment: If you are allowed to store the result in an ArrayList or just print out to console then you only need two loops. One to find the max value and the second to store/print the indices of the duplicates. If you are strictly only allowed to use arrays, then you would need three loops. One to find max, second to count duplicates (use this value to initialize result array) and change the value to Integer.MAX_VALUE, so that in the 3rd loop you'll know which index to add when you see Integer.MAX_VALUE. This sounds like an assignment, so I'm not going to spoil you with code :). Best of luck.

Comment: I must "list" the indices. So, figured it out with just 2 loops and printing the indices. Turned out pretty simple that way. Thank you everyone for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can't use hash table (which makes the problem o(n) time complexity and o(n) space complexity), i would use just sorting the array, and check with 2 pointers if any of the values is repeated.
So after sorting the algorithm (O(nlogn)) i would make 2 variable i,j starting i at 0 and j at 1 and while j<arr.lenght, and check if there is duplicate between positions array[i] and arr[j].
Here is how i solved it in js:

```js
function areThereDuplicates(...args){//Don't worry about this, imagine like it is an array
    args= typeof(args[0])=='string'?args.sort():args.sort((a,b)=>a-b)//I sorted the array
    let i=0
    let j=1
    while(j<args.length){
        let el= args[i]
        let secEl=args[j]
        if(el===secEl){
            return true
        }
        i++
        j++
    }
    return false
}
```